# Typo in Ios react native unrecognized

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I add my folder "font" on my assets, then i link my typo on Xcode (copy bundle and build phases of my project)

I create a js page and i add :

```
module.exports = {
  assets: ['./assets/font'],
};
```

i do npx react native link but when i lunch my project i have the error
"unrecognized font family Ambit-Black"

[image]
Did i missed something ?

Comment: Could you please use the font name instead of the of file name `fontFamily: 'Ambit'`?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the next pattern:

- for iOS `fontWeight+fontFamily`
- but for Android `fontFamily` is a filename of font

```js
export const fonts = {
  semibold: Platform.select({
    ios: { fontWeight: '600', fontFamily: 'Graphik LC' },
    android: { fontFamily: 'Graphik LC_semibold' },
  }),
  bold: Platform.select({
    ios: { fontWeight: '700', fontFamily: 'Graphik LC' },
    android: { fontFamily: 'Graphik LC_bold' },
  }),
  normal: Platform.select({
    ios: { fontWeight: '400', fontFamily: 'Graphik LC' },
    android: { fontFamily: 'Graphik LC' },
  }),
};
```

```js
<Text style={styles.text}>Test<Text/>

//...

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    ...fonts.semibold,
    fontSize: 14,
  },
});
```

FS:

```
assets/fonts
├── Graphik LC_bold.otf
├── Graphik LC.otf
└── Graphik LC_semibold.otf
```